# php-gtk2 installation on windows 7

Tags: php-gtk

i have downloaded the second link as shown , unzipped it. copied everything from php folder of my xampp installation into this php-gtk folder. im trying to run php-gtk sample helloworld.php program from the command prompt by typing drive\php-gtk2\helloworld.php. i have renamed php (application file) to php-gtk in this folder. It opens up test file in text editor but doesn't run it.

[image: Download]

[image: Command Prompt]
How to install and run program in php-gtk.Any help. Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

After downloading php-gtk, extract everything in a folder, let's say php-gtk, put that folder in any drive of your choice, then open php files with gtk code by

right click on the file

open with

browse to the folder php-gtk(in the drive u saved)

then select php.exe or php-win.exe

also you can run the program from command line by typing

cd C:\php-gtk

php YOUR_FILE_NAME.php